# Priority REST API: how to fetch filtered collection

Tags: rest

I have a Priority REST API question here.
For example:

1. I need to fetch records where UDATE >= MYDATE:
   `$filter=UDATE ge MYDATE`
2. I need to fetch records where record's FNCITEMS_SUBFORM UDATE >= MYDATE:
   `$expand=FNCITEMS_SUBFORM&$filter=UDATE ge MYDATE`

Is it possible to fetch collection using this 2 filters working as OR logical operator?

I looked for some hint in API documentation https://prioritysoftware.github.io/restapi/ but I didn't find anything.